# Looking for an instrumental piano piece in a sci-fi series

Tags: music, music-identification, mobile-suit-gundam, gundam-wing, toonami

I have a DISTINCT memory of a piano instrumental in one of the Gundam series' that aired on Toonami, presumably in the early 2000's or late 90's. I didn't follow the series, but I distinctly remember this piece moving me. It was slow, and the only thing I recall is I think there were robots fighting (specific, I know) and it was cutting between that and some person in an unlit mansion-type building being all melancholy and whatnot. I may have even made that memory up, I have no idea.

I also recall that for whatever reason, this scene or episode had some weight, perhaps it was the end of a plot arc or one of the series'?

Sorry for the vagaries, I was between six and eleven when this aired on Toonami. There is apparently no shortage of piano between the Gundam series' ( I don't know how many series' there are, just at least a few ) so I am having significant trouble finding and identifying it, considering I know nothing about the Gundam series' (I have a strong hunch it was the Gundam Wing one)

If someone could give me a name of the song or at the very least a video of the scene so I can confirm, that would be nice. It's been eating away at me for about ten years.

Comment: My guess is this would be from *Gundam Wing*.  Maybe from the *GW* film *Endless Waltz*?

Comment: Honorable mention for the song Kara Thrace was hearing from the pianist late in the *Battlestar Galactica* reboot. Robots fighting. Piano. Slow music. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be referring to the [Toonami remix of the track "Decisive, but Pathetic"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXI77dCbDww) of the *Mobile Suit Gundam OST*. They played this track during the credits of the English dub and it featured Amuro floating toward the White Base crew which occurs in the file moments of the series.

***Image Source: Gundam Wikia***

[image: Amuro floating toward the White Base crew]

A scene that occurs prior to this is the duel between Char and Amuro inside space fortress A Baoa Qu. The part of the fortress that they are fighting in is quite nice (maybe the mansion you were thinking of). Due to the fact that the Zeon are about to lose this final decisive battle of the One Year War - the place is in pretty bad shape and therefore not the best lit environment. This is the boiling point of their rivalry and the last episode of the series.

***Image Source: Gundam Wikia***

[image: duel between Char and Amuro]

Answer (score 0):

This episode of Gundam wing seems to fit what your describing, The end of the episode had Relena looking sad, standing in the partial ruins of a mansion, after her part was interrupted by a Gundam fight, its pretty weighty because Hero just told Relena he wanted to kill her, yet he still dances with her. the scene I believe you want is stretched out over the last 5 min or so.